# How to change lat and long params in polymer google map components

Tags: google-maps, polymer

Well, i found it on the web:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Google Maps con Polymer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/google-map.css">

<script src="components/platform/platform.js"></script>
<!-- 2.- La sentención (link rel="import") nos permite importar Web Components personalizdos
        en este caso estamos importando el de google-map -->
<link rel="import" href="components/google-map/google-map.html">

</head>
<body>

<google-map lat="37.790" long="122.390"></google-map>


</body>
</html>
```

It shows me San Francisco, EEUU. But when i change the params(lat and long):

```
<google-map lat="-30.761" long="-57.990"></google-map>
```

it shows me the same map.

i change the same params in the google components in the file: "google-map.html"

This is the piece of code:

```
<script>

Polymer('google-map', {

/**
 * A Maps API key. To obtain an API key, see  developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key.
 *
 * @property apiKey
 * @type string
 */
apiKey: null,

/**
 * A latitude to center the map on.
 *
 * @attribute latitude
 * @type number
 * @default 37.77493
 */
latitude: -30.761111,

/**
 * A longitude to center the map on.
 *
 * @attribute longitude
 * @type number
 * @default -122.41942
 */
longitude: -57.990111,
```

and it functions for me.

So i need to solve this situation: Obtaining the map i want but only with the params i call in the main index of the application. And the component code must not be touched or rewritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes names should be `latitude` and `longitude`

`<google-map latitude="-30.761" longitude="-57.990"></google-map>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code from the [Google Maps Tutorials page](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30.761, -57.990),
          zoom: 14,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Additionally, you can set the **zoom** (zoom: 3-21) and disable the **scroll wheel** (scrollwheel: true/false)

Comment: ok! thanks for your early answer.. but the idea is using web components... so you can create the map whatever you want so many times.